# MoviePlayerViewController transition causing crash

Tags: iphone

I've been rattling my brain trying to figure this out -- I am playing some videos with MoviePlayerViewController, but when I try to shake to play a random video via the accelerometer, I get a crash when it tries to switch to the new movie.

Here is the code that plays the movie:

```
            -(void)playMovieAtURL:(NSURL*)theURL { 
         MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL]; 

          if (theMovie){
         [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
          theMovie.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
         [theMovie.moviePlayer play];
         [theMovie release]; 
    }
}
```

And here is the accelerometer code:

```
- (void) accelerometer: (UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate: (UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
if (self.lastAcceleration) {
    if (!shakeDetected && IsDeviceShaking(self.lastAcceleration, acceleration, 0.7)) {
        shakeDetected = YES; 


NSLog(@"Shake detected"); 

   int filescount = [entries count];
   int randomIndex;

   for( int index = 0; index < filescount; index++ )
   {
    randomIndex= arc4random() % filescount;
    [entries exchangeObjectAtIndex:index withObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
   }

   AppRecord *app = [entries objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
   contentController.detailItem = app;
   [self playMovieAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:app.applink]]; 
  }
  else if (shakeDetected && !IsDeviceShaking(self.lastAcceleration, acceleration, 0.2)) {
            shakeDetected = NO;
        }
    }
 self.lastAcceleration = acceleration;
}
```

The crash occurs when it switches videos at this spot:

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
```

The debugger error when I shake to change videos is :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from UINavigationController to MPMoviePlayerViewController while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'

Any suggestions and ideas are greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: Have you found a way to solve this (Other than calling a method some fractures of a second later)?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a similar problem when a install my app for the first time on the device.  When I try to play a video the app crashes.  I am also using the 
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovieView]; call.
Here is the stack dump from the debugger.

```
#0  0x3037fd7c in ___forwarding___
#1  0x30312680 in __forwarding_prep_0___
#2  0x35203dee in -[MPMoviePlayerViewController viewDidAppear:]
#3  0x324128bc in -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:]
#4  0x323959da in -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:]
#5  0x3239588e in -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:]
#6  0x32412556 in -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:]
#7  0x3237a97a in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
#8  0x3237a884 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
#9  0x343557c0 in run_animation_callbacks
#10 0x34355662 in CA::timer_callback
#11 0x30352a5a in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
#12 0x30354ee4 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer
#13 0x30355864 in __CFRunLoopRun
#14 0x302fe8ea in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#15 0x302fe7f2 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#16 0x31a776ee in GSEventRunModal
#17 0x31a7779a in GSEventRun
#18 0x323272a6 in -[UIApplication _run]
#19 0x32325e16 in UIApplicationMain
#20 0x000022ca in main at main.m:14
```